# preventing duplicate entries with INSERT IGNORE

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, sql-insert

With the following, `CHECKINDATEENTERED` will always be different but `VENUECREATEDAT` will always be the same.

I was wondering if it would be possible for me to prevent duplicate entries by checking only one column in the table `createdAt`.

```
SQL = "INSERT IGNORE INTO CHECKINS (CHECKINPLATFORM, MEMBERID, VENUENAME, VENUELAT, VENUELNG, VENUECITY, VENUECOUNTRY, VENUECREATEDAT, CHECKINDATEENTERED) VALUES ('"& strFoursquare &"', '"& objMembers("MEMBERID") &"', '"& strVenueName &"', '"& strlat &"', '"& strlng &"', '"& strCity &"', '"& strCountry &"', '"& FormatDateMySQL(strcreatedAt) &"', '"& FormatDateMySQL(NOW) &"')"
```

Comment: I really, really hope those values are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `UNIQUE INDEX` then entries that conflict on this key will be ignored. You need to establish your "duplicate" conditions by creating an index on the specific columns relevant to their unique identity.

Comment: There is a ID column which is the primary key. Do you refer to it?

Comment: The `PRIMARY KEY` column is obviously unique, but you're not inserting it, are you?

Comment: Its on auto increment. Ah, what you wrote above is like a different language for me. Can you please explain me "You need to establish your "duplicate" conditions by creating an index on the specific columns relevant to their unique identity." with an example

Comment: A more concrete example is a user database where `username` is required to be unique, or a restaurant booking where the index would be on `user_id, restaurant_id, date` limiting people to one reservation per restaurant per day. You'll need to determine the minimum set of columns that define "uniqueness' in your case.

Comment: Tadman, what I am doing is letting people insert their check in dates in the CHECKINS table. so one individuals will have many check ins but different CreatedAt dates. If he will submit another check in with an existing CreatedAt date, I dont want it re-inserted. How can I set it up the way you explain me

Comment: If you want it exclusive to a user + date pair, then add a `UNIQUE` index on those two columns. That will avoid duplicates. In your case it's probably `MEMBERID, CHECKINDATEENTERED`.

Comment: I cant make MEMBERID unique, I get the following error; #1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 3

Comment: If you already have duplicates, you'll have to remove them. One way to do this is create another table that's identical to the one you're working with `CREATE TABLE x LIKE y`, add the index to that, and then `INSERT IGNORE INTO x SELECT * FROM y` to de-duplicate it. You can re-name the tables afterwards.

Comment: But I am pretty sure that I dont have duplicates. Each member has at least 5-6 check ins but they all have different `CreatedAt` values.

Comment: Are you sure you're making a `UNIQUE` index on more than one column? The definition should be like `(MEMBERID, CHECKINDATEENTERED)` in your case.